# Is it possible to poll in Camel without consuming the message?

Tags: java, email, apache-camel

I'm trying to poll an email address to see if emails have been received.  I'm running into a problem configuring an endpoint for this route because no such place exists.  I do not want to consume, use or modify these messages in any way.

Is it possible for me to configure a route such that it merely searched for the existence of this email?

For example:

```
from("imaps://imap.gmail.com?username=foo@gmail.com&" + 
            "password=RAW(bar)&" +
            "searchTerm.subject=keyword&" +
            "unseen=true&" +
            "delete=true")
            .aggregate(constant(true), new UseLatestAggregationStrategy())
            .completionSize(2).completionTimeout(30000L);
```

Is there a way to configure this so that it doesn't need a 'to' statement at the end?  I've read over the API and nothing seems to jump out at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the aggregator must have an output, you can just route to a `log` endpoint, and if you do not want something to be logged, then set the logging level to off

```
.to("log:nothing?level=OFF")
```

- http://camel.apache.org/log